# could not loop a random.randint and generate new numbers like a dice

Tags: python

this is my code I tried to loop the dice to generate new numbers every time like a dice using for but it didn't work please help me to make a code that would generate new numbers like a dice

```
import random

n=" "
for i in (n):
    dice=random.randint(0,6)
    print(a)
```

Comment: Why is `n=" "`? Have you tried it with `n=range(10)`, or maybe `n=10` and in the for loop: `for i in range(n):`?

Comment: You're assigning `dice` and the printing `a`.

Comment: Too many typos on this code. I think this needs to be closed. OP needs to review code and ask questions only if there is a real issue. code typos shouldn't be encouraged as answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want one number everytime you run, just remove the for loop

```
import random

dice=random.randint(0,6)
print(dice)
```

If you want unlimited numbers, prefer using a while loop

```
import random

while True:
    dice=random.randint(0,6)
    print(dice)
```

If you want a specific number of roles, use a for loop with range

```
import random
for i in range(10):
    dice=random.randint(0,6)
    print(dice)
```

The only error I could see except for some useless lines was assigned the value to dice but printed a

Comment: If you want multiple random numbers with numpy, it's more idiomatic to pass a `size` argument than to loop.